# C++: Do linkers detect Multiple declaration and multiple definition errors detected in .so files during compile time?

Tags: c++, c

For my application "X", I am trying to link an existing library "L". L is used by other applications as well. L has dependencies on 3 libraries, Dep1, Dep2 and Dep3. Dep1,Dep2 and Dep3 have thousands of common symbols (class names, enum Names) with X. So bringing all these libraries into X, is a big task for me.

I have 2 options:

a) Static linking(libL.a) of L (and Dep1, Dep2, Dep3) , I will refactor the symbols and data types in a different namespace (I have code access to L, Dep1, Dep2, Dep3) and resolve symbol collisions.

b) If I use a stand-alone shared object linking (.so file) do I need to worry about multiple declaration and multiple definition errors?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the namespaces in your application "X"? Modifying 4 other libraries to not conflict with 1 your application sounds like too much work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. X itself is made of many static libraries handled by several teams.

Comment: Multiple declaration/definition link time errors are the least of your worries. Multiple declarations are only an issue for stuff that gets linked into the same shared object. If the shared object links with another one that defines the same symbol, it's not a factor. What is your primary worry would be symbol resolution at runtime. Things may get resolved to different addresses, for the given symbol, from the given library. On Linux, the [dlsym(3) man page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/dlsym.3.html) gives the algorithm. You need to figure out if it will work for you.

Comment: Presumably, L/Dep1/Dep2/Dep3 cross-reference each other but have no _internal_ conflicts. So, I assume that X has conflicts with L. You can use a linker script to rename symbols without having to recompile. You could (e.g.) rename all X symbols: foo becomes Xpgm_foo. You could use `readelf -s` to get symbols and feed it to a perl/python script that generates the linker script

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will explore these suggestions.